# how to set a csrf token in react js next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, csrf-token

i am trying to fetch my graphql api from the frontend, earlier i was using axios and i solved that with code but on next js i am not able to use axios on getstaticprops  so i decided on using the fetch but it show csrf cookie not set in my backened server

data.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export async function getStaticProps() {
     const query = `
     query{
        filterBooks(title:"text book" id:5){
          id
          title
        }
      }
       `;
     const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql/';
     const opts = {
         method: 'POST',
         headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
         body: JSON.stringify({ query }),
      };
     const res = await fetch(url, opts);
     const data = await res.json();

     return {
         props: { ninja: data },
         revalidate: 1, // will be passed to the page component as props
     };
  }

   const data = ({ ninja }) => {
   const [data, setdata] = useState(ninja);
   console.log(data);
     return (
         <div>
             <form action=''>
                  <input type='text' />
                  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
             </form>
        </div>
     );
  };

export default data;
```

Comment: "i am not able to use axios on getstaticprops" - Could you elaborate on that? Why not?

Comment: No after many try I was able to do that, pls kindly give me the solution for axios, previous solutions are not working